# extraer variable de funcion dentro de llamada JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo una llamada con JavaScript y quiero manipular dicho datos mas adelantes en otras funciones, como podria hacerlo.. este es ejemplo de mi codigo...

```
$.get("https://api.test.com/",
function (data) {
variableGlobal = data[0].one;
}, "json");
```

tambien la llamada con AJAX me funciona;

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.test.com/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                var variableGlobal = data[0].one;

            }
        });
    });
});
```

lo que en si deseo es poder utilizar `variableGlobal` con cualquiera de las dos llamadas mas adelante.... en otras funciones ect..

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La podes definir por fuera de toda función y será global, el valor que tome luego dependerá de como la modifiques

```js
var variableGlobal = "Valor Inicial";
var reloj = Date.now();

console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "recien declarada", variableGlobal);

setTimeout(function(){
    variableGlobal = "5 segundos timeout";
    console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "a los 5 segundos de empezar", variableGlobal);
},5000);

$.get("https://api.test.com/",
function (data) {
   variableGlobal = data[0].one;
   console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "$.GET", variableGlobal);
}, "json");

// tambien la llamada con AJAX me funciona;

$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.test.com/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                variableGlobal = data[0].one;
                console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "$.ajax : success", variableGlobal);
            },
            complete: function(data){
                variableGlobal = "COMPLETE";
                console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "$.ajax : complete", variableGlobal);
            },
            error: function(data){
                variableGlobal = "ERROR";
                console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "$.ajax : error", variableGlobal);
            }
           
        });
    });
});

function cambiarValor(){
   variableGlobal = "valor cambiado";
   console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "dentro de cambiarValor()", variableGlobal);
}

console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "casi fin del codigo", variableGlobal);

cambiarValor();

console.log(Date.now() - reloj, "fin del codigo", variableGlobal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

Agregué un "reloj" que cuenta los milisegundos para cada console.log.

Fijate cómo las llamadas ajax (y el cambio del valor de la variable) son fuera de sincronía (asíncronas) con respecto al código lineal.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciona, es decir, si hago un console.log al final del código de variableGlobal sigue dándome el "Valor Inicial", también intente declarar la variable sin contenido al comienzo del código y aun así me muestra la variable "undefined" al final.....

Comment: es que si no se modifica por código no se cambia el valor.